# Multiply Multiple Cells by a Number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I imagine there's a simple solution to this but I can't find it.

I have a set of cells, say D16:AA29. Each row of cells contains integers, for example:

```
|8|6|7|9|5|12|7|9|2|0| //etc
```

I would like to go through these hundreds of cells, and multiply each one by say 0.8. I know how to do this via a simple multiplication formula such as

```
=A1*B1
```

My issue is - how do I *replace* the current value with the new answer, and how do I expand this multiplication across the selection of cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Type `0.8` in a cell and select it (CTRL+C)
2. Select the range you want to modify
3. Go to - home - paste - paste special, in the pop-up window mark "Multiply" then press Ok.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you sir. Will accept once the timer runs out.